# Space Shooter Unity 5 Collisions not working

Tags: unity, meshcollider, convex

After upgrading the official [Space Shooter Tutorial](http://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/projects/space-shooter) to **Unity 5**, collisions stop working.

Additionally, the following error is reported:
***Non-convex MeshColliders with non-kinematic Rigidbodies are no longer supported in Unity 5.0.***

Answer (score 8):

Luckily the error message is quite self explanatory.

The solution to this problem is to **check Convex** for all the **Mesh Colliders** found in the project.

Only the **Player** *GameObject* should have a **Mesh Collider** in this project. So check **Convex**, and make sure that **Is Trigger** is checked as well.

[image]